# setting the dual monitors in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm setting the dual monitor in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
I only have one DP port and one HDMI port so I connect monitors in each port.
But my desktop can't recognize the one in the HDMI port and only one monitor in the DP side is working.
I have already update my graphic driver but it still doesn't work.
Anyone can help me?
I'm currently using Geforce RTX 2060.
Xrandr is like this.

```
xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x1bd
Timestamp:  14751
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 1 
CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
BorderDimensions: 4 
    supported: 4
Border: 0 0 0 0 
    range: (0, 65535)
SignalFormat: TMDS 
    supported: TMDS
ConnectorType: DVI-D 
ConnectorNumber: 4 
_ConnectorLocation: 4 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x1be
Timestamp:  14751
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 1 
CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
BorderDimensions: 4 
    supported: 4
Border: 0 0 0 0 
    range: (0, 65535)
SignalFormat: TMDS 
    supported: TMDS
ConnectorType: HDMI 
ConnectorNumber: 1 
_ConnectorLocation: 1 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1c0) normal (normal left inverted right x 
axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
Identifier: 0x1bf
Timestamp:  14751
Subpixel:   unknown
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
_MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 1 
CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff0010acf6404c373635
    261b0104a53c22783a4815a756529c27
    0f5054a54b00714f8180a9c0d1c00101
    010101010101023a801871382d40582c
    450056502100001e000000ff004e3134
    54503739493536374c0a000000fc0044
    454c4c205032373137480a20000000fd
    00384c1e5311010a2020202020200019
BorderDimensions: 4 
    supported: 4
Border: 0 0 0 0 
    range: (0, 65535)
SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
    supported: DisplayPort
ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
ConnectorNumber: 0 
_ConnectorLocation: 0 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
1920x1080 (0x1c0) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
1600x900 (0x1c1) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
    v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
1280x1024 (0x1c2) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
1280x1024 (0x1c3) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
1152x864 (0x1c4) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
    v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
1024x768 (0x1c5) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
    v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
1024x768 (0x1c6) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
800x600 (0x1c7) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
800x600 (0x1c8) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
640x480 (0x1c9) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
    v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
640x480 (0x1ca) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x1cb
Timestamp:  14751
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 1 
CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
BorderDimensions: 4 
    supported: 4
Border: 0 0 0 0 
    range: (0, 65535)
SignalFormat: TMDS 
    supported: TMDS
ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
ConnectorNumber: 0 
_ConnectorLocation: 0 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out this situation.
I just have to connect my HDMI cable in the graphic card port not the other HDMI port

Comment: Obviously, that goes without saying. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.